# Java.Error when calling python script with Runtime

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, runtime, jython

I have to calling python script in java project.I dont use jython because in script i using todoist-api. I tried use this:

```
try {
    String cmd = "/home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm/venv/lib/stmtest1.py";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}
catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

I get

```
" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm/venv/lib/stmtest1.py": error=13, Permisson denied"
```

I try change permission with chmod -r 777, and other commands but i get this error again.

Ubuntu 18.04 lts. JDK 10. Intelij idea community edition.

Comment: It is saying permission denied

Comment: execute your command with sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I solve my problem

1. Recreate my project without virtual environments (venv)
2. Add shebang in python script
3. With pip3 add lib todoist-app
4. In calling python script i write:

   String cmd = "python3.6 /home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm2/stm.py"; Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: if you want use venv in calling need to write: "pipenv run /home/your directory"

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

First manually check with `sudo` permission.

And modify:

```
String cmd = "sudo python /home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm/venv/lib/stmtest1.py"
```

Comment: in this case in Ubuntu it will ask for password if you only use `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

use your command like this, echo your password then use sudo -S along with your command

```
String cmd = 'echo your_password|sudo -S python /home/kiryushin/projects/python/stm/venv/lib/stmtest1.py';
```